# Meteor Mongo Collection Update Doesnt work

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

Here is my code

```
Meteor.users.after.insert(function(userId, doc) {
  //console.log("Ekleme Yapıldı -> cid :" + doc.profile.companyId);
  console.dir(doc);
  UpdateCompany(doc.profile.companyId);
});

function UpdateCompany(companyId) {

  Companies.update({
      _id: companyId
    }, {
      $set: {
        'rootUserAdded': true
      }
    },
    function(err, affectedDocs) {
      if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Update Succes.");
        console.dir(affectedDocs);
      }

    }
  );
```

Log message shows update but it doesnt  update the collection. I wanna update company collection when a user added to users collection.

Comment: If it shows Update Succes, what did affectedDocs show? Are you running this code server side?

Comment: affectedDoc shows 1. and so ı tried code at server side with Meteor.call.. result is same.

Comment: I solve it. Problem is collection2 autoValue property.  Update result is autoValue's return value. I missed it.